# Calculate fraction of ones along an columns/rows divided by the minimum fraction of ones

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to create a function `calc_frac(a, axis=0)` that takes a 2D array and returns the proportion of ones in each column or row divided by the column or row that has the smallest proportion of ones.

So for example

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]])
print(calc_frac(a))
```

should return `[ 2.  2.  1.]` because column 3 has the smallest proportion of ones (1/3) so I divide all proportions by 1/3, since the other column proportions are 2/3, their ratio is (2/3)/(1/3)=2.

From reading the numpy docs, I understand I can go about this two ways- `np.sum()` or `np.count_nonzero()`... I understand that I need to find the the mean so possibly also `np.mean()`, but then how would would I find the minimum proportion of ones? I'd say I'm a little stuck with what method to use here.

Comment: They all would work. Pick your favorite. Or even try them all and pick the fastest...

Comment: This is a bit like asking "I'm given a Ferrari, a Jeep or a caravan for free. Which one should I choose?" Stackoverflow is not an opinion poll tool.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Haha. I'm not sure it's exactly like your analogy loool. Isn't the Ferrari the obvious pick of those? Same thing with my question- one is not like the other... Isn't that what Stackoverflow is for? asking questions? Which is what I'm doing here..."Ernest"..

Comment: I would pick the caravan, since spending 4 weeks of holiday with the whole family in a Ferrari is really not much fun. I hope you see my point: When asking a question about different options, you need to provide clear criteria by which to judge. Primarily opinion-based questions are simply off-topic on SO.

Comment: "Pythonic" is rather a moving target. Do you need help creating the function? Or did that work but the function isn't really reabable or is too slow? Maybe you can formulate where you need help a bit more clearly and then [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I'd say I'm a little stuck with what method to use. I understand that I need to find the the mean so use np.mean() possibly, but then how would would I find the minimum proportion of ones?

Comment: @dejz I've edited the question based on your comment. If I messed something up feel free to rollback the edit or parts of it. I think it's much less opinion-based now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that you were stuck with an approach to solve this. One possibility is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]])
axis = 1

# Create a mask where ones are True and zeros False
ones = a == 1
# Sum the number of ones along the axis, using the fact that booleans act like integers
# True = 1, False = 0
onesaxis = np.sum(ones, axis=axis)
# Minimum of the ones along that axis
minaxis = np.min(onesaxis)
# Divide the amount of ones in each axis by the minimum number
result = onesaxis / minaxis
```

If you want it shorter put multiple statements in each line (approach is the same):

```
onesaxis = np.sum(a == 1, axis=axis)
result = onesaxis / np.min(onesaxis)
```

If your array only contains 1 and 0 you might not need the `a == 1` step, simply use the array itself:

```
onesaxis = np.sum(a, axis=axis)
result = onesaxis / np.min(onesaxis)
```

One warning though: You probably need to special case the case that one row contains zero `1`s. Otherwise you'll get division by zero, which is almost never correct:

```
onesaxis = np.sum(a, axis=axis)
minaxis = np.min(onesaxis)
if minaxis == 0:
    raise ValueError() # or something else
result = onesaxis / minaxis
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Yeah I added a `if min == 0: raise ValueError` but I'm still getting weird runtime warnings, although I'm not sure if that's a PyCharm thing or a legitimate concern lol

Comment: @dejz What runtime warnings? I'm glad it helped (please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer). Some additional points: Don't use `min` as variable name, that's the name for a built-in function (generally you could use `arr_min` or `min_along_axis` to avoid this conflict). :)

Comment: so my test is: 
`try:
   calc_frac(a)
   print(False)                                                                                                      
except ValueError:
  print (True)` 

`print(all(celc_frac(a,1) == np.array([1.,   1.])))
print(np.allclose(calc_frac(b),
                           np.array([6., 4., 4., 1., 5., 6., 4., 6.])))
print(np.allclose(calc_frac(b,azis=1),
    np.array([3.5, 2.5, 1. , 3. , 1.5, 3. , 2. , 1.5])))`
and so when I run that I get: `RuntimeWarning:divide by zero encountered in true_divide
False
   result = oneaxis / np.min(oneaxis)
True`

Comment: what is `b`? Note that such technical discussions in the comments are hard to follow. Could you share the program?

Comment: Oh, true my bad. I've got some other code at the top that pertains to testing.
`a = np.array([[1,0],[1,0]])
npr.seed(101)
b = npr.randint(2,size=(8,8))
c = npr.rand(8,8)` this stuff I used to test 
`def calc_frac(a, axis=0):
    return a.mean(axis=axis)`

Comment: oh maybe it has to do with my raise ValueError statement... for 
`if np.min_along_axis(___):` I need arguments within that right? (sorry this is really annoying ahah)

Comment: @dejz I edited the answer, to include an example. Check it out :)

Comment: ahh! thanks so much I really appreciate it, that did the trick. sorry for any confusion haha